# Regex for reject characters ;*&%^=""

Tags: regex

I need to validate an input field using regex but the input field should not be present for these characters `;*&%^=""`.

Regex which I wrote `\A.+[a-z0-9A-Z]+\Z`, did not validate.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a negated character class.

```
^[^;*&%^="]+$
```

This matches any character one or more times but not the one present inside the negated character class.

- `^` Asserts that we are at the start of a line.
- `[^...]` Negated character class which matches any character but not the one present inside that particular character class.
- `+` after the char class would repeat the char class one or more times.
- `$` Asserts that we are at the end of a line.

Answer (score 2):

Another way:

```
str = "Why won't this *!&!!* code run??!"
str.tr('*&%^"=', '') == str #=> false

str = "Now it works, but I have no idea why!!"
str.tr('*&%^"=', '') == str #=> true
```